# Links can be lost over time; can I do something about it?

Tags: discussion

I'm looking at an old question and answer, which has been enormously helpful to me. (In case you are wondering: [Elitism in GA: Should I let the elites be selected as parents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622342/elitism-in-ga-should-i-let-the-elites-be-selected-as-parents))
However, the link they have provided no longer works. Some of the answers reference whatever the paper was. I can't comment anyway (but even if I could, I don't know whether it would be appropriate). I dug around on the site I was redirected to and I believe I found the reference. (Currently it is http://www.omgwiki.org/hpec/files/hpec-challenge/ga.html but, as before, that could change).

Still, next time I might not be so lucky (it could be totally gone!). If I find a question or answer like this, what should I do to respond?

Comment: It's up to you how much you want to do about it. Usually a comment is enough unless you wanted to edit it yourself, though since you don't have enough rep to do so, you can't. Not much you can do about it.

Comment: "Nothing" is a fine answer. I don't know why this is a bad question. I checked the help center, and it is not open-ended/subjective, although there may be multiple correct answers. I think it is a question about how to use the site. Do I misunderstand? Am I not really supposed to be on meta?

Comment: a single downvote doesn't mean it's a bad question.

Comment: this is actually something we've looked at before in quite some detail in terms of system automation; however, we have no great and magic options. Ultimately, if it is a useful answer, it may be worth finding an up to date link - but this simply isn't always possible, and we can't snapshot the entire internet :(

Comment: Isn't it just http://www.omgwiki.org/hpec/files/hpec-challenge/ga.html ?